# ngx Pagination. Can I use with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to ask that is possible use some bootstrap's paginatinon to ngx Pagination ? I would like to use mechanism from ngx Pagination and css from bootstrap.

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69009387/7186739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your own template and customise the styling if that's what you're trying to do to look like bootstrap:

https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#paginationcontrolsdirective

https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination#styling

An example here:

http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/custom-template

Or you could use `ngx-bootstrap` :)

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/pagination

Answer (score -1):

Apply Bootstrap style on "ngx-pagination" Component

After installation ngx-pagination, add this style in your custom style sheet or in your component related style file

```
.ngx-pagination{
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
.ngx-pagination li{
    margin-right: -1px !important;
}
.ngx-pagination li.current{
    background-color: #007bff !important;
    border: 1px solid #007bff !important;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
    position: relative;
}
.ngx-pagination li a:focus{
    outline:none;
}
.ngx-pagination a, .ngx-pagination button{
    color: #007bff !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;

}
.ngx-pagination .disabled{
    color: #6c757d !important;
    pointer-events: none  !important;
    cursor: auto  !important;
    background-color: #fff  !important;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6  !important;
    padding: 6px 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you consider using Bootstrap's variables for color, paddings and other customizable things? Your solution only works for default theme and it doesn't include any hover effects.